# Music is not playing on release apk .using library react-native-track player

Tags: react-native, audio-player, react-native-track-player

React naive app Music is not playing on release apk .using library react-native-track player.

It works fine with local host both in emulator and real device while debug mode.
Is der any specified place to keep mp3 files ?
I'm trying to load from bundle only
I'm a windows machine user

Please refer this git below you may clone it as well..

https://deva11@bitbucket.org/deva11/trackplayertest.git

**Debug Mode** :

[image: DebugMode]

**Release Mode**
[image: Release Mode]

in reference to **react-native-sound** .I am aware that music files should keep in **android/app/src/main/res/raw** folder and while bundling assets in react-native folders will be merging with android native folders.

**How can I match it up ?**

Comment: were you able to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been fixed in [6c57395](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player/commit/6c57395173cb2469914eb42f03162ed2b12af531).

In release mode, React Native used to copy all resources into the `drawable` directory, and react-native-track-player used to look up the files there.

After an update, React Native started copying non-image files to the `raw` directory, and that broke the feature.

---

In case someone is looking for an answer, the proper way to load files from the device, is to prepend the path with `file:///`, here's an example:

```js
TrackPlayer.add({
    url: 'file:///storage/sdcard0/Music/song.mp3',
    // ...
});
```

And the proper way to load files inside the app bundle is to `require`/`import` them:

```js
TrackPlayer.add({
    url: require('./song.mp3'),
    // ...
});
```

If that doesn't work, feel free to open an issue in the [react-native-track-player](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player/issues) repository

Comment: I am facing same issue while loading media from network. It works in debug mode but doesnt work in release bundle. Is there any fix for that?